# Calling C++ program from a function?

Tags: c++, github, bioinformatics, fasta

So I'm pretty new to C++ and programming in general, and I'm trying to figure out how I can use code from [this](https://github.com/alexpreynolds/kmer-counter) github program inside my own program. How do I write a function that calls the program and returns the results?

Comment: Windows or *nix?

Comment: You might consider [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) if on Linux

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) is the reference to `std::system`. With this you can run any command on a POSIX system.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::system("ls -l >test.txt"); // execute the UNIX command "ls -l >test.txt"
    std::cout << std::ifstream("test.txt").rdbuf();
}
```

If you need a other platform (e.g. Windows) take a look at [boost process](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/process.html).

Answer (score -1):

This is done by asking the system to create a new process, so your solution will depend on the system you are on.

You can use directly the system interfaces to create the process, or use a cross-platform third party wrapper such as Qt or boost.